# Cannot run Common Lisp code on Jupyter Labs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, common-lisp, jupyter-lab

I just installed the [Common Lisp kernel](https://github.com/yitzchak/common-lisp-jupyter) on Jupyter but I cannot run even the simplest function.

For example, when I run:

`(+ 2 3)`

I get the following error output:

```
SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR: invalid number of arguments: 7
 
3: ((FLET "H1" :IN JUPYTER:EVALUATE-CODE) invalid number of arguments: 7)
4: (SB-KERNEL::%SIGNAL invalid number of arguments: 7)
5: (ERROR invalid number of arguments: 7)
6: (SB-INT:%PROGRAM-ERROR invalid number of arguments: ~S 7)
7: ("INVALID-ARG-COUNT-ERROR" 7)
8: (SB-KERNEL:INTERNAL-ERROR #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X0360CB30) #<unused argument>)
9: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
10: ("foreign function: funcall2")
11: ("foreign function: interrupt_internal_error")
12: ("foreign function: signal_emulation_wrapper")
13: (SB-C:COMPILE-IN-LEXENV (LAMBDA NIL (PROGN (+ 2 3))) #<NULL-LEXENV> NIL #<SOURCE-INFO {10054FB893}> 0 NIL NIL)
14: (JUPYTER/COMMON-LISP::EVAL-AND-PRINT (+ 2 3) 0 NIL)
15: ((:METHOD JUPYTER:EVALUATE-FORM (JUPYTER/COMMON-LISP:KERNEL T T T)) #<unused argument> #<FORM-TRACKING-STREAM for "file /private/var/folders/2m/jgjftc_50v7174pkpy0q6g4c0000gn/T/8D5CF88911FF45F031383A7D6553D461-2332295794.lisp" {10054FCE53}> CELL:2332295794.LISP.NEWEST NIL #<unused argument> #<unused argument>)
16: (JUPYTER/COMMON-LISP::REPL (+ 2 3) CELL:2332295794.LISP.NEWEST NIL)
17: ((:METHOD JUPYTER:EVALUATE-CODE (JUPYTER/COMMON-LISP:KERNEL T)) #<unused argument> (+ 2 3) CELL:2332295794.LISP.NEWEST NIL)
18: (JUPYTER::HANDLE-EXECUTE-REQUEST)
19: (JUPYTER::RUN-SHELL #<KERNEL {10034490D3}>)
20: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN BORDEAUX-THREADS::BINDING-DEFAULT-SPECIALS))
21: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
22: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-4" :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
23: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE))
24: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-1" :IN SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX))
25: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-MUTEX #<CLOSURE (FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-MUTEX-THUNK :IN SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE) {360DD3B}> #<MUTEX "thread result lock" owner: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "SHELL Thread" RUNNING {1004762CB3}>> NIL T NIL)
26: (SB-THREAD::INITIAL-THREAD-FUNCTION-TRAMPOLINE #<THREAD "SHELL Thread" RUNNING {1004762CB3}> NIL #<CLOSURE (LAMBDA NIL :IN BORDEAUX-THREADS::BINDING-DEFAULT-SPECIALS) {1004762C5B}> NIL)
27: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp")
28: ("foreign function: new_thread_trampoline")
29: ("foreign function: _pthread_body")
30: ("foreign function: _pthread_body")
31: ("foreign function: thread_start")
```

Not sure why it says I have 7 arguments when there are only two.

I followed all the instructions and even installed the `zeromq` and `czmq` packages with homebrew.

Any thoughts? Did I miss anything during the installation process?

Here's a screenshot:
[Error in Jupyter Labs with Common Lisp code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvnmH.png)

Comment: Did you try opening an issue on Github? Also the versions of your libraries will be useful.

Comment: Instead of jupyter try better org-mode - it can do everything jupyter can do. Especially plotting right after the cell.